# Отслеживание изменений коллекции List<string> c#

Tags: c#

Не уверен, что правильно сформировал вопрос.
Есть два инкапсулированных поля:

```
    public static List<string> UndoBufferedLines { get; set; }

    public static List<string> BufferedLines { get; set; }
```

По ходу кода к `BufferedLines` часто применяет `.Add(some value)`. Это вызывает `get` в свойстве, который возвращает поле `bufferedLines`, после чего происходит его изменение.

Мне необходимо сохранять предыдущий вариант этого поля в `UndoBufferedLines`, по сути для реализации функции `Undo`:

```
BufferedLines = UndoBufferedLines;
UndoBufferedLines.Clear();
```

Через `set` я это не могу сделать, так как сеттер не вызывается у меня совсем.
Как сделать правильно буффер коллекции?

Comment: 1) Сделать поля приватными 2) Сделать метод в классе `AddBuferedLines(...)`, в жтом методе запоминать всё, что вам надо.

Comment: @tym32167 не очень полнял, что это даст. Сделав их приватными я потеряю возможность обращаться к ним из других классов, а что тогда передавать в метод? Обращение к полю не только с Add происходит, и Count, и Cleare, Find и т.д.

Comment: сделать два дополнительных приватных поля, а в свойствах, возвращать ссылки в них!

Comment: Вместо `List<T>` можно использовать [BindingList<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?view=netframework-4.8) или [ObservableCollection<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8). У этих классов есть события изменения коллекции: подписываемся и делаем, что необходимо. Или можно написать свой вариант коллекции с похожими событиями.

Comment: наружу вы можете выдать `IEnumerable<>` или `IReadonlyCollection<>`  вместо списка, чтобы клиенты не изменяли ваш список сами, а все изменения происходили через ваш код.